# Is it possible to inject the public part of an ephemeral key into an OVA using the packer virtualbox-ovf builder?

Tags: virtualbox, packer

Packer 1.4.0 introduces a feature to generate ephemeral keys for the builders virtualbox-iso and virtualbox-ovf. All of the examples given use virtualbox-iso and show injecting the public part of the key using kickstart scripts or similar.

I would like to use this feature to update an existing OVA file with packer using the virtualbox-ovf builder.

Using the virtualbox-ovf builder is it possible to inject the public part of the key into the OVA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it via `boot_command` by logging into the console and adding the pubkey there.